# Bootstrap framework without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have requirement to develop a front end project. I am planning to use angular + bootstrap. I don't have to use jquery, but bootstrap javascript components require jquery. my question is,
1)Can we have bootstrap built on javacript.
2)Can we have bootstrap built on angular.

please provide related good documents on any above two related topics.

Comment: To use bootstrap component (which requires jquery) must requires jquery.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

Comment: Use UI Bootstrap. [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: but can we use both angular and jquery plugin. How its good to use both???

Comment: @Arun To use bootstrap component you must have jquery.

Comment: And use jQuery src before bootstrap src to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

For angular project you can user UI Bootstrap which have bootstrap CSS file with a set of native AngularJS directives.It does not require jQuery or Bootstrap's Javascript.The only required dependencies are:

- AngularJS
- Angular-animate
- Bootstrap CSS

Check it [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

Have no worry, the internet is full of scripts and tutorials, native JavaScript is the coolest programing language ever! Far more powerful and requires almost zero maintenance on very long periods of time.
Also some features are even better.

If you are looking for Bootstrap without jQuery or vanilla Javascript for Bootstrap, you can use [bootstrap.native](https://github.com/thednp/bootstrap.native)

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap plugins are jQuery plugins, so no, strictly speaking, you can't use them without jQuery. There is [this project](https://github.com/tagawa/bootstrap-without-jquery), however, which may help you.

Answer (score -1):

When building out Angular projects, you should not add on the full jQuery library. jQlite is already included in Angular and this should be all the jQuery that is necessary.

[Reference](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together)